# How to check if the set of numbers contains a certain number in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, html

I'm creating this school project that has this `<select>` tag where if the `<option>` value is equal to a certain number, it will not show, display or print.

Example: if the set of numbers is 1,2,4,5,9 then only the `<option>` tag that has a value of 3,6,7,8,10,11,12 will show.

```
<select name="">
    <?php
        $set_of_numbers = "1,2,4,5,9";

        for($i=0; $i<=12; $i++) {
            if($i != $set_of_numbers) {
               echo '<option value='.$i.'>'.$i.'</option>';
            }
        }
     ?>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be able check the numbers in the set programmatically, like so:

```
<select name="">
    <?php
        $set_of_numbers = [1, 2, 4, 5, 9];

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
            if (!in_array($i, $set_of_numbers)) {
                echo '<option value='.$i.'>'.$i.'</option>';
            }
        }
     ?>
 </select>
```

If your `set of numbers` is and can only be a `string`, then you would probably go with something like this:

```
$set_of_numbers = "1,2,4,5,9";
$set_of_numbers = explode(',', $set_of_numbers); // This makes an array of the numbers (note, that the numbers will be STILL stored as strings)
```

If you want to be able to compare the numbers as integers, the solution would be:

```
$set_of_numbers = "1,2,4,5,9";
$set_of_numbers = json_decode('[' . $set_of_numbers . ']'); // This creates a valid JSON that can be decoded and all of the numbers WILL be stored as integers
```

Hope, you've got this :)

Comment: Great it works, so that's how in_array works. Thanks!!

Comment: the second solution you explain to me, fits my project very well!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

Do the following changes to your code, this should work.

`$set_of_numbers = array(1,2,4,5,9)
   ... 
   if (!in_array($i, $set_of_numbers))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_diff to only get the numbers that is not in the list.

```
$set_of_numbers = "1,2,4,5,9";
$numbers = explode(",", $set_of_numbers);
$range = range(1,12);

$numbers_to_output = array_diff($range, $numbers);
// [3,6,7,8,10,11,12]

foreach($numbers_to_output as $n){
    echo '<option value='.$n.'>'.$n.'</option>';
}
```

This way you only loop the values that you want to echo.
Other methods will loop all values and need to compare each value to your list of numbers.

https://3v4l.org/ub8II

---

The code can be condensed in to:

```
foreach(array_diff(range(1,12), explode(",",$set_of_numbers)) as $n){
    echo '<option value='.$n.'>'.$n.'</option>';
}
```

Comment: Yeah, differentiate the array in the first step would also have a lower performance cost.